# Infinite Scroll + Bootstrap 4 Grid Does Not Scroll As It Should

Tags: bootstrap-4, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement the Infinite Scroll (https://infiniteajaxscroll.com) with the Bootstrap 4 Grid, but it doesn't scroll as the originial script does. On the first video I show, when I scroll down, the new items are loaded, but the position keeps down, so the user actually sees the last item:

https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cF1ThrFFgx

On this second video I show how it should work correctly:

https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cF1ThTFFg5

On the second video I got it working by removing the **flex** and **max-width** properties from the **.col-** definition of Bootstrap, but then, the layout is broken. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us your code, videos are not usefull.

Comment: This issue has been solved during development. Not sure what was the issue. But probably **position: relative;** of the parent element was the problem.